# Using Object Orientated subclasses in a separate form

Tags: oop, subclass, delphi-2010

**I have created a factory unit that contains multiple subclasses for different functions.**

FACTORY UNIT

```
//parent 
type
 TfactoryU = class(Tobject)
 public
 constructor create;
 end;

 //subclass 1
 TFormPosition = class (TfactoryU)
 private
 fFormName:tform;
 public
 constructor create (formName:tform);
 procedure centerForm(frm:tform);
 end;

implementation

{ TfactoryU }

constructor TFormPosition.Create(formName:tform);
 begin
   Inherited Create;
   fFormName:=formname;
 end;

procedure TFormPosition.centerForm(frm:tform);
begin
  frm.Left := (Screen.Width - frm.Width) div 2;
  
frm.Top := (Screen.Height - frm.Height) div 2;

end;

constructor TfactoryU.create;

begin

end;
```

However, I do not know how to call the subclass procedure from a different unit.

MAIN UNIT

```
procedure TfrmMERCH.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);

var

objfactoryU:TfactoryU;

begin

objfactoryU:=tformposition.create(frmmerch);

objfactoryU.centerForm(frmmerch);
```

The calling of the procedure centerForm is underlined in red.

Comment: you mentioned there is an underline, but it is not visible, please edit you question with the proper formatting, or add comments in the code to indicate your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`centerForm()` is not a member of `TfactoryU`, that is why you get an error when trying to call it via a `TfactoryU` variable.  You need to use a type-cast to reach it, eg:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMERCH.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  objfactoryU: TfactoryU;
begin
  objfactoryU := tformposition.create(frmmerch);
  tformposition(objfactoryU).centerForm(frmmerch);
```

However, since both the declaration of `objfactoryU` and the call to the `centerForm()` method are in the same procedure, you should just change the declaration instead:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMERCH.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  objfactoryU: tformposition;
begin
  objfactoryU := tformposition.create(frmmerch);
  objfactoryU.centerForm(frmmerch);
```